# bootstrap-wysihtml5 and Bootstrap X-Editable textarea: editor buttons appearing with no styles or icons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to integrate [bootstrap-wysiwyg5](https://github.com/jhollingworth/bootstrap-wysihtml5) within my (already implemented) [Bootstrap X-Editable](https://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/).

However, the editor is appearing with no styles and missing buttons.

[image]

Not really sure what to do here.

JS & HTML

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(
        function(){
            $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                }
            });

            $('.testedit').editable({
                validate: function(value) {
                    if($.trim(value) == '')
                        return 'Value is required.';
                },
                type: 'wysihtml5',
                title: 'Edit Comment',
                placement: 'top',
                send:'always',
                ajaxOptions: {
                    dataType: 'json',
                    type: 'post'
                }
            });
        }
    );
</script>

<a href="#" class="testedit" data-type="wysihtml5" data-pk="{{ $each_comment->id }}" data-url="{{ url($each_comment->post_id . '/comment/update') }}">
    {!! $each_comment->comment !!}
</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change the css classes in `bootstrap-wysihtml5-0.0.2.js`

I searched for all `<a class="btn">` and I simply added `btn-default`

I also edited their icons, instead of `<i class='icon-picture'></i>` I used `<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-picture'></i>`

Now buttons are clear and icons show.